# search results in table with rows limit php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I created a web site and i added search option which show search results in table, i want to limit rows number to 5 by page please help me to do that:

i would like also to make search results in random sort for each search operation, not the same results are shown on the first page each search :

this is my search code :

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE company LIKE '$company' and activity LIKE '$activity'");

    echo "<h3>search results</h3><p>";
    echo "<table border='1' align='center' >

    <tr>
        <th>phone</th>
        <th>city</th>
        <th>activity</th>   
        <th>company</th>
    </tr>";

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['phone']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['city']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['activity']. "</td>";    
        echo "<td>" . $row['company']. "</td>";   
    echo "</tr>";

      }
      echo "</table>";

    $anymatches=mysql_num_rows($result );
    if ($anymatches == 0)
    {
    echo "<h3>sorry no results</h3>";
    }
    ?>
```

thank you.

Comment: use php pagination http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/29.html

Comment: *sidenote:* stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. Here is a good [tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ) for PDO.

Comment: this link may be helpful http://phpro.org/tutorials/Pagination-with-PHP-and-PDO.html

Comment: Also, use CSS to style a table instead of using attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query first into

```
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM table WHERE company LIKE '%$company%' and activity LIKE '%$activity%' ORDER BY RAND()");
```

We can use a counter to limit the fetching to 5.

```
$counter=1;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

if($counter<6){
        echo "<td>" . $row['phone']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['city']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['activity']. "</td>";    
        echo "<td>" . $row['company']. "</td>"; 
}

else {
/* NOTHING TO DO */
}

$counter=$counter+1;

} /*   END OF WHILE LOOP   */

$anymatches=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if ($anymatches == 0)
    {
    echo "<h3>sorry no results</h3>";
    }
```

**OR** you can try this, just changing your query into:

```
$query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE company LIKE '%$company%' and activity LIKE '%$activity%' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5");
```

***Please make it clear, if you want to show only 5 results or a pagination with 5 rows per page.***


**If pagination is what you're looking for:**

We should start by storing the data first into a table storage. For example we have a table named **search** with even just one field, *searchfield*.

```
$searchword=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['searchword']);

mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE search SET searchfield='$searchword'");

/* this is where you store your search text for later purposes */
```

And we'll fetch it right away (Don't get me wrong, this is for the pagination purposes)

```
$selectsearch = "SELECT * FROM search";
$querysearch = mysqli_query($con, $selectsearch) or die(mysqli_error($selectsearch));

while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($querysearch)){
$search = $rows['searchfield'];
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE company LIKE '%$search%' OR activity LIKE '%$search%'"; /* do your query search */

$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$r = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
$numrows = $r[0];

echo '<b>&nbsp;'.$count.' result/s found for "'.$search.'"</b>';
$rowsperpage = 5;
$totalpages = ceil($count / $rowsperpage);

if (isset($_GET['currentpage']) && is_numeric($_GET['currentpage'])) {
      $currentpage = (int) $_GET['currentpage'];
} else {
     $currentpage = 1;
} 

if ($currentpage > $totalpages) {
   $currentpage = $totalpages;
} 
if ($currentpage < 1) {
   $currentpage = 1;
} 

$offset = ($currentpage - 1) * $rowsperpage;

$select="SELECT * FROM table WHERE company LIKE '%$search%' OR activity LIKE '%$search%' LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage"; /* do the query again but with limit */
$result=mysqli_query($con, $select);

/*start of the table*/
{  
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
    <th>phone</th>
    <th>city</th>
    <th>activity</th>   
    <th>company</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['city'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['activity']. "</td>";    
  echo "<td>" . $row['company']. "</td>";  
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

  }

echo '<table border="0"><tr><td>';

/*  *****  build the pagination links *****     */
$range = 2;

if ($currentpage > 1) {
   $prevpage = $currentpage - 1;
   echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$prevpage'>Previous</a> ";
} 


for ($x = ($currentpage - $range); $x < (($currentpage + $range) + 1); $x++) {

   if (($x > 0) && ($x <= $totalpages)) {
      if ($x == $currentpage) {    
         echo " <font color='#546f3e'><b>$x</b></font> ";
      } else {
         echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$x'>$x</a> ";
      } 
   }              
}  

if ($currentpage != $totalpages) {
   $nextpage = $currentpage + 1;
     echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$nextpage'>Next</a> ";

} // end if
/*  ***** end build pagination links *****      */
echo '</td></tr></table>';
```

Comment: No problem. Glad I helped you out.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't written any pagination code, use MySQL LIMIT , clause.

For ordering randomly, try this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE company LIKE '$company' and activity LIKE '$activity' ORDER BY RAND()
```

Answer (score 0):

Start with this. In this you need to pass the page number in URL (Eg yourwebsite/your-php.php?page=0)

```
        $page = $_GET['page'];
        $perPage = 5;
        $start = $page * $perPage;
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE company LIKE '$company' and activity LIKE '$activity' limit " . $start . ',' . $perPage);

        echo "<h3>search results</h3><p>";
        echo "<table border='1' align='center' >

        <tr>
            <th>phone</th>
            <th>city</th>
            <th>activity</th>   
            <th>company</th>
        </tr>";

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
        {
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['phone']. "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['city']. "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['activity']. "</td>";    
            echo "<td>" . $row['company']. "</td>";   
        echo "< /tr>";

          }
          echo "</table>";

        $anymatches=mysql_num_rows($result );
        if ($anymatches == 0)
        {
        echo "<h3>sorry no results</h3>";
        }
        ?>
```

You need to implement pagination in to this by giving link to different page numbers.

I suggest to use some MVC framework rather than having all data retrieval and view in one file.